# Does `fetch_page()` just not guarantee a minimum amount of results when used with `filter()`?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queryclass) we have:

```
page_size: At most this many results will be returned.
```

It looks like when using `filter` along with `fetch_page`, it doesn't return a minimum of results, even though there are more results which actually match the query. Is that really the case?

Is it possible for `fetch_page` to result zero results, even though if keep going by continuing from the returned `cursor`, we'll find more results eventually?

And, if that's the case, and I need a minimum amount of results, does it mean that I have to "manually" accumulate results until I get to the desired number of entries? Or is there are a feature in NDB which will allow me to "automatically" accumulate results until I have a certain minimum number of results?

Here's the code in question I'm using:

```
results, cursor, more = (cls.query(keys_only=True)
                         .filter(cls.user_id == user_id)
                         .filter(cls.expired == False)
                         .order(ordering)
                         .fetch_page(batch_size, start_cursor=start_cursor))
```

In my test environment most of the results saved in the database don't match the filters, but there are still quite a few that do, and don't appear

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your query, it either uses a specific composite index or follows a merge join algorithm.  The performance of merge join queries is described at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/optimize-indexes#index_merge_performance .

As noted in that doc, it's possible for the query to match fewer than `batch_size` results in the RPC deadline, and thus return without `batch_size` results.

If the RPC successfully returns and has zero results, more should be false.  If the RPC can't find any results, but isn't done scanning, it may return an error.

If you really need `batch_size` results you should verify that you get have `batch_size` results by issuing your query multiple times, and by updating start_cursor on every call.  You should also use a few indexes as possible for serving your query.

The full document at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/optimize-indexes should be helpful for you.